# jQuery .append outside tag

Tags: jquery

I'm completely new to jQuery. To be honest it is my first few days.

And there is my first question.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.head-span').parent().addClass('head-h').append('<div class="clx" />')
});
```

**As a result I have this**

```
<h1 class="head-h"><span class="head-span">This is Some Heading</span><div class="clx"/></h1>
```

What do I need to do in jQuery so my .clx will appear after . like this

```
<h1 class="head-h"><span class="head-span">This is Some Heading</span></h1><div class="clx"/>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check next to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [`after()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content) instead of `append()`

```
$('span.head-span').parent().addClass('head-h').after('<div class="clx" />')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the div after the header, don't append it, use the [`after`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after) method:

```
$('h1').after('<div class="clx" />');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`after` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#selector), like this:

```
$('span.head-span').parent().addClass('head-h').after('<div class="clx" />')
```