# how to display div after the ul in jquery

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I have a dynamic html code as am not able to display the `div` after `ul` without appending the html code options.

```
<ul class="products clearfix">
    <li class="post-7312" >1</li>
    <div class="productadds">field one</div>
    <li class="post-1234">2</li>
    <div class="productadds">field two</div>
    <li class="post-5678">3</li>
    <div class="productadds">field three</div>
    <li class="post-2344">4</li>
    <div class="productadds">field four</div>
</ul>
```

I want to display the code as below format

```
<ul class="products clearfix">
    <li class="post-7312" >1</li>
    <li class="post-1234">2</li>
    <li class="post-5678">3</li>
    <li class="post-2344">4</li>
</ul>

<div class="productadds">field one</div>
<div class="productadds">field two</div>
<div class="productadds">field three</div>
<div class="productadds">field four</div>
```

Woocommerce/content-product.php

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

/**
 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
 */
//do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
?>
```

in my child theme i displayed the product adds-extension using this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', array($GLOBALS['Product_Addon_Display'], 'display'), 5 );
```

my question is to display the product add-ons after the shop loop item
i am getting the above ul li inside the div i want to display the div outside of the ul. so that in the product add-ons will display the forms in outer of the ul.

Comment: Are you looking for somthing like it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462726/jquery-append-outside-tag

Comment: yes in that format but without using html append or after  code like 

`$('.products').after('<div class="productadds">field one</div>');` i dont want use html tags inside the jquery

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/medashiva/ewrxa1zz/ try this hope helps :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var x = document.createElement("DIV");
var t = document.createTextNode("This is a div element.");
x.setAttribute("style", "background-color: pink;");
x.appendChild(t);

$('.products').after(x);

})
```

Comment: thank you for your fiddle but in my concept it will not work 
i want the same div to display after the ul without using the html code
var x = document.createElement("div");
i dont want this format of code.

Comment: Then write a hidden div show it after page load or after certain time.

Comment: thats also will not work in this concept what i am asking is display the div after the ul. i mentioned in that code

Comment: how ul prints, i mean its ajax call or normal loop one. could you please give us more information.

Comment: i used woocommerce hooks for this concept the ul is fixed its from dynamic part i hooked the functions into child theme